# Ambiguous Redirect error in bash script

Tags: xml, bash, unix, redirect

The following lines of code correspond to ambiguous redirect errors, respectively.

```
echo -e "\t<other>" >> $xml

echo "</direntry>" >> $xml
```

line 62: $xml: ambiguous redirect

line 76: $xml: ambiguous redirect

Looking around the site it seems that this problem stems from variables not having double quotes around them, but if I change $xml to "$xml" I get a no such file or directory error.

Answer (score 2):

Double-quote your variable which you are writing to, it is most *likely* because of the `xml` variable containing one or multiple spaces present. The double-quotes present preserves your variable value intact and does not let it undergo [word-splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting).

```
echo -e "\t<other>" >> "$xml"
```

Comment: This does not work for me. It still results in bash: : No such file or directory and the variable has no space.